Does the bottom rotor on a Coaxial quadcopter spin faster?
On the typical setup of a coaxial quadcopter, does the bottom rotor spin at a higher rpm than the top rotor? Or does it have different pitch, or is it exactly the same as the top rotor?

source

To reduce cost, quadcopters reduce how many different parts they have.  So on each arm, the upper and lower motors are usually the same, as are the "rotors" (propellers;  making a cw/ccw pair that is an exact mirror image is cheaper).  So each arm's top rotor and bottom rotor share the same RPM:  the flight controller software that converts pilot commands to individual motor speeds is typically the same for one or for two motors per arm.
For efficiency, the downstream prop's RPM, pitch, and diameter should correct for the propwash that it's in.  But that optimization's worthwhile only for much larger, more expensive setups.

Packing List. Motors: 8 Pieces

If they used only four motors they would need gearboxes to invert the direction of one of the rotors in the coax pair. For many applications, the choice between "motor or gearbox" is a no-brainer with gears being cheaper, able to handle more torque and being needed anyways. I suppose drones are an exception, because the rotors spin at extremely high RPM.

Reversing such a "BLDC" motor needs no gearbox.  You just swap two of the three wires that power it from its "ESC" electronic speed controller.

@CamilleGoudeseune if you only want to use 4 motors you need to use gearboxes...

Ah, I misunderstood.  Y'all mean one motor driving two contrarotating propellors.  Yeah, that needs gears.

@leftaroundabout "being needed anyways"...what you mean by that?

@Gabe lots of applications need a gearbox for reasons unrelated to direction-inversion (most typically to get more torque). If you have a gearbox anyways then there is no point adding an extra motor to avoid using gears to invert direction.

If one motor is loaded with less torque, it will naturally spin faster. This doesn't exactly result in equal lift from the two motors or equal power, but it compensates the propwash effect at least partially.
Quadcopter motors are usually voltage controlled (actually fixed voltage + pwm). Only the voltage is actively controlled, the other parameters (rpm, torque, power, current) then settle on some equilibrium. If one motor is loaded with less torque, it will naturally spin faster. The flight controller will usually send the same throttle setting (pwm value) to both motors. There is no active compensation for propwash effect.
If you build a coaxial quadcopter, you can use different propellers for top and bottom, e.g. 5x3" and 5x4". That's your choice and you may indeed get better performance compared to identical propellers. You don't have to worry about adjusting rpm because each motor/propeller combination will find its own equilibrium.

These are almost universally brushless DC motors. They spin exactly as fast as they are commanded to.

@EugeneRyabtsev - No, BLDC motors are not commanded to spin at a certain RPM, otherwise they'd be synchronous AC motors. BLDC Motors have exactly the behavior described in my answer.

They exhibit that behavior in open-loop control system only. Is there normally one loop per motor or one loop per pair?

@EugeneRyabtsev - The 8-motor quadcopter still has only four control loops (roll, pitch, yaw, collective). The feedback signals for those loops come from gyro/accelerometer/altimeter. There is no RPM feedback, hence open loop control with respect to RPM.

Packing List. ESC: 8 Pieces

Meaning those loops. I assume some sensing per motor (either back EMF or direct).

@EugeneRyabtsev - Yes, that's what I told you. 8 motors on 8 separate ESCs -> each motor/propeller/esc will find its own equilibrium RPM. The flight controller only sends throttle commands to the ESCs, not RPM commands.

Okay, I might have misunderstood this. Was under the impression it works like this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/255491/29238

I agree with this answer. Usually quadcopter ESCs convert the throttle command to PWM duty cycle, with no explicit RPM regulation loop. The PWM duty cycle will roughly correspond to RPM, but not exactly due to winding resistance and inductance.

@EugeneRyabtsev: Making a BLDC motor spin smoothly at a certain speed requires that one not only drive the commutation waveform at that speed, but also that feeds the motor the right voltage.  If the voltage is too high, the motor will start spinning faster than the commutation speed until the rotor position gets ahead of the rotating magnetic field, and then slow down until the rotor position falls behind the magnetic field, then speed up, then slow down, etc.
